# How to use Modular Trees

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

I'm trying to make trees in blender using the GitHub Modular Trees addon but whenever I try it always gives me an error message. I also can't find any tutorials on how to use it and the directories don't help at all. Thank you for your help!